# RBS - Do the Microsoft.Data.SqlRemoteBlobs.Maintainer.exe.config settings need to be the same on each server?

Tags: sharepoint-server, content-database, remote-blob-storage

I'm setting up RBS and looking at adding an additional content database. The instructions that I'm reading mention to add the connection string to the `Microsoft.Data.SqlRemoteBlobs.Maintainer.exe.config` file. This file is on the sql server and the WFE's.

Does this file need to be the same for each server that RBS is installed or is it maintained only be the sql server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is RBS maintainer which role is clean the Blob (data deleted from SharePoint also removed from BLOB). This can be run from any machine that has access to the DB and the blob store(s).

TO clean up you have to schedule a task and yes you have to add a connection string for each content database.

http://www.karthikscorner.com/sharepoint/remote-blob-storage-rbs/

Comment: Ok. So only server I use to schedule the maintainer on would need to be configured. Thank you.

Comment: yes thats correct...that server should have access to all DBs